# how to use includes/partials in Rails 3 Backbone ejs.jst files

Tags: backbone.js, ejs, jst

I'm using the backbone-on-rails gem with javascript (as opposed to coffeescript) to render views for a model.  Everything works fine, but my view code is kind of long so I'd like to refactor things out to use includes/partials.

Heres' my code:

in my views/model_show.js file

```
AppName.Views.ModelNameShow = Backbone.View.extend({

  template: JST['main'],

  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
  },

  render: function() {
    this.model.fetch({async:false});
    $(this.el).html(this.template({ model: this.model }))
    $('#main_content').html(this.el);
  }

});
```

in my templates file I'd like to so something like this in templates/main.jst.ejs

```
<% if(this.model) { %>
    <h2> model found</h2> 
    <%- include top_section %>
    <%- include middle_section %>
    <%- include bottom_section %>
<% } else { %> 
    <h3>Claim not found <a href='#'>Back</a></h3> 
<% } %>
```

where top_section would be a file under templates (like templates/top_section.jst.ejs)

Problem is I keep getting the following errors (firebug output).

> SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical [Break On This Error]
>
> ...2> model found \n\t',(''+ include top_section ).replace(/&/g,
>   '&').replace(/

which causes this error because the template isn't rendered

```
TypeError: this.template is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

$(this.el).html(this.template({ model: this.model }))
```

I should mention that I've tried a few different syntaxes like the ones below, but those just throw different errors.

```
<%= include top_section %>
<%- include(top_section) %>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a stop-gap for now I just created a hash of templates and enumerate over them in the render.  Not ideal, but works for now.  Here's what the code looks like now.

views/model_show.js file

```
AppName.Views.ModelNameShow = Backbone.View.extend({

  templates: {
    top_section: JST['top_section'],
    middle_section: JST['middle_section'],
    bottom_section: JST['bottom_section']
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
  },

  render: function() {
    this.model.fetch({async:false});
    var zuper = this;
    $.each(this.templates, function(key, value) {
      //iterate over each template and set the html for the div with id=key with template
      //For example $('#top_section).html(JST template for top_section)
      $('#' + key).html(zuper.templates[key]({ model: zuper.model }))
    })
  }

});
```

template file looks like this now.

```
<% if(this.model) { %>
    <h2> model found</h2> 
    <div id="top_section"/>
    <div id="middle_section"/>
    <div id="include bottom_section"/>
<% } else { %> 
    <h3>Model not found <a href='#'>Back</a></h3> 
<% } %>
```

As I said -- not ideal, but a functional workaround for now.

Answer (score 0):

In EJS the correct syntax for a partial is this:

```
<%= this.partial({url: 'templates/partial.ejs'}) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrew,but it still didn't work for me. I'm thinking it's something in the .jst.ejs chain that's casuing things to break and being new to both I'm just not seeing it.